# Something wrong with this gtk# class for a window?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, gtk#

Learning C#, I feel so guilty for loving it. I'm a microsoft hater. Anyways I'm trying out gtk# and just trying out some simple stuff. I've made a class for the main window and MonoDevelop is complaining about this code, which I swear was just fine a second ago.

```
public class mwin
{    
    protected Window win = new Window("test program--");    

    public mwin()
    { 
        //Configure the parts    
        win.SetDefaultSize(300,500);
    }

    public void showWin()
    {    
        win.ShowAll();      
    }    
} 

win.SetDefaultSize(300,500);
}--<(here it says "} expected")
```

But obviously I have a closing brace! Am I missing something?

[edit]
here's whole code. The color stuff was some stuff I was playing around with to color the window, but I didn't finish because the error started. I'm sure it's not the color stuff because it still has an error when I comment them out. http://codepaste.net/b2mwys

Comment: Is this the whole file? Also, if you're using MonoDevelop and GTK#, you're most likely using Mono, so you might want to retag it.

Comment: nope, using .net framework on windows. Just using MonoDevelop and GTK# to make habits that are cross platform since I also use Linux sometimes.

Comment: If you like C# and GTK, but hate Microsoft, you might consider using Vala: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vala_%28programming_language%29 ;-)

Comment: I'm actually checking it out now. I'm not a C programmer, the reason I'm trying to learn C# is to learn something with a little more power and documentation behind it. I like that it looks a lot like normal C, is it easy to translate see examples into vala?

Comment: @Isaiah: Vala is basically C# on top of GObject (the Gnome-Object-Library instead of .NET/Mono) which gets compiled into native, C-compatible code.

Comment: Your current code shouldn't work at all there is one more close brace than there is open brace.

Comment: the last two lines are referencing the correct code above it. Sorry they shouldn't be in the code box

Answer (score 1):

You have put your call to "win.SetDefaultSize(300,500);" outside of a method block. The compiler is expecting a closing brace.